# Include in std::regex search, exclude from std::sub_match using std::regex_token_iterator

Tags: c++, regex, c++11

I want to tokenize a `std::string` using whitespace characters as delimiters, but between a pair of quotes no delimiters should be considered and no other quotes should be allowed. To achieve this, I use the following [regex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) (*represented as a raw string literal*):

```
R"((\"[^\"]*\")|\S+)"
```

which gives the following output when used as the [`std::regex`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/basic_regex) of a [`std::sregex_token_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_token_iterator):

**Test sample** [[Try It Online](https://wandbox.org/permlink/uDOqz6pYQFWyuzrd)]:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <regex>

int main() {
   std::string text = "Quick \"\"\"\" \"brown fox\".";
   std::regex re(R"((\"[^\"]*\")|\S+)");
   std::copy(std::sregex_token_iterator(text.cbegin(), text.cend(), re, 0),
             std::sregex_token_iterator(),
             std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, "\n"));
}
```

**Test output**:

```
Quick
""
""
"brown fox"
.
```

This results in the inclusion of the surrounding quotes in the sub matches. Instead, I want to get rid of these surrounding quotes. To do so, I can obviously modify the iterated sub matches manually, but I wonder if it is possible and how one can achieve to eliminate the surrounding quotes using the [`std::regex`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/basic_regex) and the [`std::sregex_token_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_token_iterator)?

**Changelog**: I minimized/reduced the regex thanks to [YSC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5470596/ysc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something along these lines, perhaps:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <regex>

int main() {
   std::string text = "Quick \"\"\"\" \"brown fox\".";
   std::regex re(R"((\"([^\"]*)\")|(\S+))");
   std::transform(
       std::sregex_iterator(text.cbegin(), text.cend(), re),
       std::sregex_iterator(),
       std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, "\n"),
       [](const std::smatch& m) { return m[2].length() ? m[2] : m[3]; });
}
```

[Demo](http://rextester.com/LRTNJU60709)

Comment: Using `std::transform` is one way of modifying the iterated sub matches manually which I like to avoid. I rather hope (since I am not sure if it is possible) I can modify the `std::regex` instead. That way I can write a reader that can handle an arbitrary `std::regex` if provided. Otherwise the default `std::regex` can be used. Your proposed solution, however, requires to let the user pass the lambda function as well in order to still support arbitrary regexes.

Comment: No, I don't believe you can express that within regex syntax alone. The caller would have to pass in additional information in some form - a lambda, or perhaps simply a list of submatch indexes from which to pick the first non-empty one.

Comment: Normally, capture groups are supported for regexes, though this probably is problematic in combination with the `std::sregex_iterator` (i.e. by modifying the fourth constructor argument, I can iterate a single sub match without surrounding quotes)? Languages like Perl even have look-ahead/look-behind support, but I do not think C++'s `std` supports something like this (yet)?